# Alternar conteúdo de páginas mudando apenas a div

Tags: jquery, html

Estou criando um site, onde eu quero usar a div da pagina principal para alternar entre outras páginas. Por exemplo, tenho a 'index', 'conteúdo 1' e 'conteúdo 2'. Quero fazer com que quando eu clicar no link, troque o conteúdo da 'index' para 'conteúdo 1', sem ter que carregar outra página, mantendo a logo, menu e rodapé do site normais.

Quero saber como faço isso em código, por que já tentei alguns que vi a galera fazendo, de várias maneiras e não deu jeito, a div não ta mudando para a div da página que requisitei. Lembrando que uso o Wamp, a página tem o link da biblioteca no header e etc etc.

Editado:
Então @AsuraKhan, eu li sua resposta e fui procurar entender mais sobre, porém ainda não me veio a clareza. Fiz um breve resumo do que eu estou tentando fazer aqui para você entender o que eu quero fazer. Exemplo:

- Index.html

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="conteudo2.html" id="a1">Conteudo 2</a>
        </li>
        <a href="conteudo3.html" id="a2">Conteudo 3</a>
        <li>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="conteudo" class="content">
    <h1>CONTEUDO 1</h1>

</body>
```

O conteúdo 2 (conteudo2.html) e 3 só muda a class, a id é a mesma.

E o script que estou tentando é esse:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Load(View){
       $("#conteudo").load(View);
    };
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
       $("#a1").click(function(e) {
         Load('conteudo2.html'); 
       });
       $("#a2").click(function(e) {
         Load('conteudo3.html'); 
       });
    });
</script>
```

Basicamente é isso, não estou conseguindo decifrar o erro.

Comment: Está falando de Ajax?

Comment: Sim, @AsuraKhan.

Comment: na função  Load, o trecho $("conteudo").load(View), esse conteúdo, não deveria ser #conteudo? Ja que é uma ID.

Comment: Já fiz esse acréscimo, tanto nele quanto no a1 e a2, ainda sem sucesso.

Comment: esqueci de falar que tem que colocar no a1 e a2 também, já que são id. E coloca esses href com um #, ou muda pra outra coisa.

Answer (score 1):

### Sobre ajax

Basicamente, ajax é quando você faz uma chamada a um script ( não importa se é `php`, `json`, `asp`, `javascript`, `html` ). Essa chamada, faz com que o javascript busque um arquivo no servidor, que você irá específicar qual é, exemplo:

```
$(".buttonOuDiv").click(function(){
    $.get("outraPagina.html", function(data, status){
        $(".classDaDiv").html(data)
    });
});
```

Perceba que existe um `callback` na função `click(callback)`, quando o Div ou botão (caso deseje) é clicado. Isso fará com que o codigo execute o que está dentro desse `callback`. Nisso chegamos ao Ajax. Onde através do método `GET`, iremos chamar o arquivo outraPagina.html e isso irá nos fornecer alguns parâmetros.

**Data** é o conteúdo que foi retornado pelo ajax, sendo assim, é a página `outraPagina.html` dentro do `.classDaDiv` através da função .html para carregar a data dentro da div que você escolher.

**Status** é opcional, ele apenas mostra o status da resposta do `HTTP`, onde pode ser 404 ( não encontrado, 200 (OK ), 400 ( deu problema interno no servidor ).

Perceba então, que para utilizar o ajax, é necessário que você use um Servidor Web. Vejo que está usando o WAMP, então deve funcionar.